# Flue heat exchanger for guest house

Tags: heating

I recently acquired a property which has a separate guest house (or sauna house).

The building is recently built, 55 sq. meter, concrete foundation, 300mm block walls with 50-75mm polystyrene insulation with central heating (fluid underfloor with thermostats in every room).

The only heat source is currently a sauna woodburning stove. However, after 6 hours of continuous burning, the fluid temperature in heating system gets barely over ambient temperature. The heating system appears to be working correctly- system holds pressure, circulation pump is running. The water pipes from stove are cold near the stove (while the sauna-side of stove is scalding hot, so I'm fairly sure the fluid is circulating through stove, but the heat output from stove seems inadequate.

Previous owner was an avid sauna-enjoyer, so it was not a problem for him to burn 3 times a week during winter to maintain decent temperature in this house, but me- not so much. I would rather take my sauna (and burn wood) once a week at most.

To me, the solution appears to be improving heat transfer from stove to heating system.

I have seen two options- additional heat exchanger in the rocks of sauna, or a heat exchanger on the flue.

To me, the flue heat exchanger seems a more efficient way, but I'm not sure how to even ballpark estimate the heat output from such heat exchanger.

What I do know is the average mass of wood going in the stove, and can easily measure exhaust gas temperature. Manufacturers of flue heat exchangers do not provide efficiency and expected heat output numbers.

Can someone suggest either:

- A source of information on expected heat output of flue heat exchangers,
- A method to at least estimate the heat output, so I can decide, if it'll even make a dent in heating budget in my situation?

Comment: What is the heat delivery system once the fluid is hot? If it's heating the concrete mass, it's going to be slow to heat up when you've let the building cool down, but will also hold heat between firings to an extent directly proportional to the insulation of the building. "barely over abient" on the return side of such a system is fairly normal.

Comment: @Ecnerwal is right, you'll want to rule out the possibility that you're just trying to heat up a lot more mass than you realize -- perhaps more mass than is practical to keep warm for an infrequently used building. If that's the case, consider electrical heat. Not efficient but way faster response.

Comment: Heat delivery system is underfloor heating system, and it is probably heating up the concrete. It's not just return that is barely ambient- it's also the flow that's not reaching appreciable temperature.

Comment: I put a heating loop in my shop last place. I found that if I did not keep it warm it took days to heat up to the set point there was insulation below but a 6” slab it was awesome when cold outside working on a warm floor but getting it up to 60f if left off for a week could take days but moving from 60 to 75 only took a few hours. I think you may be dealing with the same thermal mass issue and the change in temperature it takes a lot of heat before you see the temp of the slab increasing you may want to install a small boiler to maintain a minimum heat level when you are not burning.

Comment: I thought I should mention for flue heat if you take two much heat out of the stack the pipe will build up cresode at lower levels and faster. We used to use bladders made of cast in the 70’s little doors acted like a heart pumping the water out causing cold water to be pulled in and it repeated it worked great for hot tubs and even house heating when we burned all the time.